# How to enable automatic updates on CentOS7?

Tags: centos, upgrade

**Introduction**

The aim is to update a CentOS 7 system automatically.

**Attempt**

Based on [this](https://serversforhackers.com/video/automatic-security-updates-centos) documentation the following steps were executed:

- `yum-cron` has been installed
- The `yum-cron.conf` was changed as follows:

  ```
  user@host ~ $ cat /etc/yum/yum-cron.conf 
  [commands]
  update_cmd = default
  update_messages = yes
  download_updates = yes
  apply_updates = yes
  ```
- The `yum-cron` was:

  - checked (`systemctl status yum-cron`)

    ```
    user@host ~ $ systemctl status yum-cron
    ● yum-cron.service - Run automatic yum updates as a cron job
    Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/yum-cron.service; enabled; 
    vendor preset: disabled)
    Active: active (exited) since
    ```
  - enabled (`systemctl enable yum-cron`)
  - started (`systemctl start yum-cron`)
- After a couple of days the yum.log was checked

  ```
  user@host$ sudo cat /var/log/yum.log
  [sudo] password for user:
  Feb 23 18:49:51 Installed: libreoffice5.2-freedesktop-menus-5.2.5-1.noarch
  Mar 02 15:42:09 Installed: qpid-tools-1.35.0-1.el7.noarch
  Mar 27 08:41:33 Installed: yum-cron-3.4.3-150.el7.centos.noarch
  ```

but nothing was installed automatically. This was verified when `yum upgrade` indicated that multiple packages could be installed:

```
user@host$ sudo yum upgrade

Transaction Summary
===================================================================================================================================================================================================================
Install    3 Packages (+2 Dependent packages)
Upgrade  155 Packages
Remove     2 Packages

Total size: 488 M
Total download size: 53 M
Is this ok [y/d/N]:
```

**Discussion**

- Q: Perhaps this issue is OS version related?

  ```
  user@host ~ $ cat /etc/redhat-release
  CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)
  ```

  A: No evidence was found that this problem is related to CentOS `7.3.1611`.

Comment: I wonder if the fact that `yum-cron` appears to have been pulled in as an update matters.  Might be worthwhile to find a second example where it fails.

Comment: Also, these options might be relevant: ```# Uncomment to auto-import new gpg keys (dangerous)
# assumeyes = True``` and `skip_broken=True`

Comment: Then I would expect that that is shown in the log (`/var/log/yum.log`) at least, .e.g. cannot install due to something

Comment: another way to troubleshoot, set it up to send message via e-mail when updates are available.  No clue why it would've failed silently, if it did.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing a great deal of parameters that are in the default `yum-cron.conf`. I wonder if the omission of some of those parameters is what's causing your problem.

Here's one of my working `yum-cron.conf` setups, decrufted:

```
# grep -v -e '^#' -e '^$' yum-cron.conf 
[commands]
update_cmd = default
update_messages = yes
download_updates = yes
apply_updates = yes
random_sleep = 10800
[emitters]
system_name = None
emit_via = stdio
ouput_width = 80
[email]
email_from = root@localhost
email_to = root
email_host = localhost
[groups]
group_list = None
group_package_types = mandatory, default
[base]
debuglevel = -2
mdpolicy = group:main
```

Also, check to be sure `/etc/cron.daily/0yum-cron.cron` exists:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Only run if this flag is set. The flag is created by the yum-cron init
# script when the service is started -- this allows one to use chkconfig and
# the standard "service stop|start" commands to enable or disable yum-cron.
if [[ ! -f /var/lock/subsys/yum-cron ]]; then
  exit 0
fi

# Action!
exec /usr/sbin/yum-cron
```

Finally, make sure SELinux labels and basic unix permissions and ownership are correct. These values work:

```
# ls -Z /etc/cron.daily/0yum-daily.cron /etc/yum/yum-cron.conf
-rwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:bin_t:s0       /etc/cron.daily/0yum-daily.cron
-rw-r--r--. root root unconfined_u:object_r:etc_t:s0   /etc/yum/yum-cron.conf
```

Comment: I will try this tomorrow and let you know the outcome.

Comment: Once changed, should it work directly? When the `/var/log/yum.log` is checked then no reports regarding updated packages are registered.

Comment: I'm adding separate answers for different avenues of investigation.

Comment: One thing I forgot to draw attention to were the UNIX permissions and ownership of `/etc/cron.daily/0yum-cron.cron`. They should be 0755 and root:root.

Answer (score 2):

One thing that may help diagnosing this is to check the root account's email. Any process Anacron runs, it will capture stdout and stderr and email those to the system root account. Also, `yum-cron` itself should send emails of any activity. It would be wise to forward root's mailbox to an email address you read.

Adding `set -x` near the beginning of `/etc/cron.daily/0yum-cron.cron` will result in `sh` echoing every command it's running, which can help you determine if Anacron is even being run, and if it's being run, whether the `0yum-cron.cron` script is executing properly.